# Eloquent Relationships - Get a unique list of entries via a pivot table. (BelongsToMany )

Tags: laravel, relationship, has-and-belongs-to-many

With a belongsToMany relationship, I get a collection of topics based on the amount of assigned questions to the catalogue. Hence, this list contains many duplicates. I am unsure if I might misunderstood the relationship model or if I am supposed to just filter out via a distinct or an array operations.

So let's assume that we have three tables *catalogue*, *topics*, *questions*. 
Whereas a questions belongs to one catalogue and one topic. *Catalogues* and *Topics* therefore can have many questions. The link between catalogue and topics is established within the questions table.

Now I want to show (a distinct list) of all *topics* which belong to a specific *catalogue* through *questions*.

See the following for clarifications:

```
| id | created_at          | updated_at          | title            | is_active | pivot_catalogue_id | pivot_topic_id |
|----|---------------------|---------------------|------------------|-----------|--------------------|----------------|
| 1  | 2020-01-22 11:51:41 | 2020-01-22 11:51:41 | Topic 1      | 1         | 1                  | 1              |
| 1  | 2020-01-22 11:51:41 | 2020-01-22 11:51:41 | Topic 1      | 1         | 1                  | 1              |
| 1  | 2020-01-22 11:51:41 | 2020-01-22 11:51:41 | Topic 1      | 1         | 1                  | 1              |
| 1  | 2020-01-22 11:51:41 | 2020-01-22 11:51:41 | Topic 1      | 1         | 1                  | 1              |
| 1  | 2020-01-22 11:51:41 | 2020-01-22 11:51:41 | Topic 1      | 1         | 1                  | 1              |
| 1  | 2020-01-22 11:51:41 | 2020-01-22 11:51:41 | Topic 2      | 1         | 1                  | 2              |
| 1  | 2020-01-22 11:51:41 | 2020-01-22 11:51:41 | Topic 2      | 1         | 1                  | 2              |
| 1  | 2020-01-22 11:51:41 | 2020-01-22 11:51:41 | Topic 2      | 1         | 1                  | 2              |
```

**ER Diagram**
[image: ERDiagram]

**Catalogue model**

```
    /**
     * Get the corresponding questions of a catalogue.
     *
     */
    public function Questions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Question::class);
    }

    /**
     * Get the corresponding topics through questions of a catalogue.
     *
     */
    public function Topics(): belongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Topic::class, Question::class);
    }
```

**Topic model**

```
    /**
     * Get the corresponding questions for a topic.
     *
     */
    public function Question()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Question::class);
    }
```

**Question model**

```
    /**
     * Get the corresponding catalogue for the question.
     *
     */
    public function catalogue()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Catalogue::class);
    }

    /**
     * Get the corresponding topic for the question.
     *
     */
    public function topic()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Topic::class);
    }
```

Comment: Are you familiar with [`hasManyThrough`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)? Might help here, I'm pretty sure it would return a distinct collection. I think in your `Catalogue` model you want to use this for the `topics` relationship.

Comment: Hey, I've tried that but then it queries the wrong fields: ``` QLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'questionnaire_topics.question_id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select `questionnaire_topics`.*, `questionnaire_questions`.`catalogue_id` as `laravel_through_key` from `questionnaire_topics` inner join `questionnaire_questions` on `questionnaire_questions`.`id` = `questionnaire_topics`.`question_id` where `questionnaire_questions`.`catalogue_id` = 1)  ```. It looks in the topics entity for the question_id rather than in the question entity. Similiar happens when I interchange the.

Comment: If it queries the wrong field, I think you have the `hasManyThrough` relationship misconfigured. Maybe post that? It can be tricky specifying all the right fields and making that work.

Comment: I've used the standard config of hasManyThrough. When checking the example you can see that users and posts contain each others foreign keys. However in my specific case ```questions``` contains both foreing keys ```catalouge``` and ```topics``` as a topic does not belong to a catalouge but the question.

Comment: So do you think that the belongsToMany relationship with unique() ```$catalogue->topics->unique()``` is the valid approach? It provides the expected output.

Answer (score 2):

You could define a BelongsToMany relationship from the Catalogue:

```
class Catalogue extends Model
{
    public function topics()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Topic::class, 'questions');
    }
}
```

But the questions table will contain records with DUPLICATE combination of catalogue_id and topic_id so $catalogue->topics will return DUPLICATE topics.

The easiest thing we can do is putting distinct() for the relationship.

```
public function topics()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Topic::class, 'questions')->distinct();
}
```

So that will remove duplicate topics.